# How to change a connection string in a DTS package at runtime from a .NET application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dts

I am trying to run a dts package from a C# application. I need to dynamically change its connection string, though. I had a look on the web and found that I should use the Variables property of the Package object. Thing is, my Visual Studio 2010 does not show this Variables attribute for the package. The namespaces I am using are

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
```

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the titles are for.

Comment: @JohnSaunders – huh? That's what the _tags_ are for?

Comment: @KennyEvitt: I think we're even - I don't know what you're referring to, and I think, since you're responding to a comment of mine from four months ago, you don't know what _I_ was referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Do you truly mean DTS (SQL2000) or its newer sibling SSIS? In any case, I had a similar problem where I had to specify multiple dynamic connections to a package.  The way I solved it was this:

From the caller:
- Write to a SQL table two columns:  
- The "Key" column was the particular connection to target
- The "Value" column was the new connection value

Inside the package:
- Use a SQL Task to read the key/value pair into @User:: variables
- Use a Script task to get a handle to the running instance of itself
  --> Assign connection strings thru this handle

DTS Example:

```
' Get a reference to self (the DTS package currently running)
Set oPkg = DTSGlobalVariables.Parent

' Get connection to Input File - Set Path
Set oCn = oPkg.Connections.Item ( "MasterFileIn" )
oCn.DataSource = workAreaPath & "MasterFile.txt"
```

SSIS doesn't allow access to the active package object, but you might be able to set the connections directly.  In your **ScriptMain.cs** file:

```
ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["MasterFileIn"];
cm.ConnectionString = Dts.Variables["DataSource"].Value;
```

Comment: Please see "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)".